# Theme Desinger using JQUery

Tags: jquery

I am developing an application to design Forms. Now i thought to add the option of desinging themes and saving it as a new theme. I want to apply the themes available including what i have designed with the one selected to my Form.Can u people suggest what is the best way to design themes . How to design themes using JQUery .Actually i am referring through wufoo.com .

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a tool called [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) that allows you to create CSS style sheets for your application. Perhaps you could just embed it to your site instead of reinventing it from the scratch.